# How to permanently turn off flash in Zxing scanner view?

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on barcode scanner using ZxingScannerView.I need to turn off the flash while scanning but **Camera** component is deprecated so is there any other alternate way to acheive this.Hereby i am attaching my code please give me some possible answers to turn off flash in zxingscanner.Thanks in advance

```
   import android.Manifest;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
   import android.hardware.Camera;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class WorkOut extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    Integer response = 0;
    int currentIndex = 0;

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        Camera camera  =Camera.open();

        Camera.Parameters p;
        p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(p);

        CameraConfigurationUtils.setTorch(p,false);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams mainParam = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(mainParam);





        //end 3
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent refresh = new Intent(WorkOut.this, MposHomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(refresh);
            }
        });

        frameLayout.addView(mScannerView);
        frameLayout.addView(scanButton);

        setContentView(frameLayout);



    }

    private void checkPermissions() {
        try {
            for (int i = currentIndex; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
                int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[i]);
                if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {
                    requestPermission(permissions[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Activity activity = this;
    Context context = this;

    String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};


    private void requestPermission(String permission) {


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permission},
            101);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    checkPermissions();
                } else {
                    try {

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (response == 1) {
            mScannerView = null;
            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
            setContentView(mScannerView);
            response = 0;

        }

        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        mScannerView.stopCamera();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d("ani", "onrestart");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scanned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply... maybe still its going to help someone.
`ZXingScannerView` itself has a set of very simple set/get method for turning corresponding camera flashlight on/off. You don't need to try using (deprecated) Camera or Camera2.

**Firstly,** to turn the Flash permanently off, just add the following line after assigning `mScannerView`:

```
mScannerView.setFlash(false);
```

**Secondly,** for toggling the flash on/off via a button, simply add the following line in the button's onClick method:

```
mScannerView.setFlash(!mScannerView.getFlash());
```

that's it :) It worked fantastic for me.

Comment: Every time the scanner get focused the flash turns off and on again when re-focusing. Why is this happening?

Comment: "the scanner get focused" ? Not clear... how do you get the scanner focused?

Comment: when it gains focus... when it acquires focus... when the image is no longer blurry. After that the scanner stops for a second and turns off the flashlight ,loses focus and turn on the light againd and so on. Why is this happening?

Comment: Lovely.. was searching for this for a long time. :)